# I want my scoring system to start from a certain number

Tags: objective-c, scoring

Hi I'm using Xcode for an app and my scoring system goes up by 1 point every second. How do i make it start at 25 and then go up at 1 point per second. This is the code:

```
-(void)Scoring{

ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", ScoreNumber];



-(void)NewGame{

ScoreNumber = 0;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: 0"];
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

In `NewGame`, you are setting `ScoreNumber` to 0.  Set it to 25 instead:

```
-(void)NewGame{

ScoreNumber = 25;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: 25"];
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it wouldn't work. It would start at 25 and then go back to 1... 2... 3... etc.

Comment: Then something is resetting it back to 0.

Comment: Typically we don't know what code we need because we don't know what code you have :)

Comment: thats really all the code about the scoring so idk I'm really a noob with coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) newGameWithStartingScore:(int)startingScore {

    // Set our label
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", startingScore];
    // Store our score in our dictionary
    NSDictionary * userInfo = [@{@"currentScore" : @(startingScore)} mutableCopy];
    // Start the timer
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(incrementScore:) userInfo:userInfo repeats:YES];
}

-(void)incrementScore:(NSTimer *)timer {

    // Get current score
    int currentScore = [timer.userInfo[@"currentScore"] intValue];
    // Increment it
    currentScore++;
    // Update userInfo ref
    timer.userInfo[@"currentScore"] = @(currentScore);

    // Set our label
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", currentScore];

    // See if timer should continue
    BOOL shouldInvalidate = NO;
    /*
     Insert validation logic here.  Set 'shouldInvalidate' to YES in order to stop the timer
     */
    if (shouldInvalidate) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }

}
```

Assuming that `Score` is a reference to a label, or something that can display text, you could call it like this:

```
[self newGameWithStartingScore:25];
```

This way, you can modify it as needed.

Comment: i keep getting semantic issues: "method definition for 'incrementScore' not found"

"local declaration of 'timer' hides instance variable"

and "local declaration of 'score' hides instance variable"

Comment: The score was left over, I removed it. The other is because you have a property also named as 'timer' name that something different.

Comment: i have
        NSTimer *timer;
Is that what you want me to change?

Comment: Change that. You no longer need it, unless you're using it for something else.